# KnockoutJS - click event firing too soon after beforeRemove

Tags: knockout.js

I've got a view model that looks something like this:

```
self.selectedItems = ko.observableArray();

self.onBeforeUnselectItem = function (elem) {
    if (elem.nodeType === 1)
        $(elem).fadeOut(function() {
            $(elem).remove();
        });
};

self.unselectItem = function (item) {
    self.selectedItems.remove(item);
    self.unSelectedItems.push(item);
};
```

My view looks like this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: {data: selectedItems, beforeRemove: onBeforeUnselectItem}">
    <span data-bind="text: Name"></span> - <a href="#" data-bind="">Remove</a>
</div>
```

My problem is that the item is being pushed into `unSelectedItems` before the fadeOut animation has finished.

Is there any way to make the call to `unselectItem` wait until the animation has finished?
I realise this is because of the way the click event is bound to `unselectItem`

**Edit**

For the time being, I put a delay in my `unselectItem` function:
(this is obviously not ideal!)

```
self.unselectItem = function (item) {
        self.selectedItems.remove(item);
        setTimeout(function () {
            self.unSelectedItems.push(item);
        }, 350);
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You're already doing it for the removal of the element. The jQuery effects and similar long-running processes run asynchronously, i.e. they don't block other JS from continuing to run. That's why `fadeOut` has a callback: to run stuff once the fade has completed. If your requirement is that the fade must complete before the item is added to `unSelectedItems`, then you must do that *inside* that callback.

Comment: That's what I thought... So i must do the removal from inside the callback of the fadeOut?

Comment: Yes. If there was a more complicated process, you could abstract it away into a function and then just call that function from the callback, but that would probably be overkill for a one-liner like this.\